# Mistake in reasoning regarding variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A$ be a 2x2 matrix, the elements of which are continuous functions in interval (0,1). It is known that the vector functions $\begin{pmatrix}1\\t-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}t+1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$ are solutions to the homogenous system $\mathbf{x'}=\mathbf{Ax}$. Which of the following functions is the second element of one of the solutions of the system $\mathbf{x'}=\mathbf{Ax}+\begin{pmatrix}t^2\\t^3\end{pmatrix}$?

1. $-\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{3}t^3$
2. $\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{6}t^3+\frac{1}{3}t^4$
3. $2t+4t^2$
4. $\frac{1}{4}t^4$

I approached this question through variation of parameters. In order not to make any mistakes on the way, I used an online calculator which gave the results $\frac{t^4+t^3-t^2}{t^2-2}$ for $C_1'$ and $\frac{t^2}{t^2-2}$ for $C_2'$, but integrating the latter does not produce any of the results above. Could anybody help out? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have the fundamental matrix $\Phi(t)=\pmatrix{1&t+1\\t-1&-1}$. The variational solution is $x(t)=\Phi(t)C(t)$. Inserting and removing the parts of the homogeneous equation for $\Phi$ gives
$$
\Phi(t)C'(t)=b
\implies 
C'(t)= \frac1{t^2}\pmatrix{1&t+1\\t-1&-1}\pmatrix{t^2\\t^3}
=\pmatrix{1+t+t^2\\-1}.
$$
As you can see, the denominators cancel. Integration is now easy. Setting integration constants to zero gives
$$
x(t)=\Phi(t)C(t)
=\pmatrix{t+\frac12t^2+\frac13t^3 -(t^2+t)\\-t+\frac12t^2+\frac16t^3+\frac13t^4+t}
=\pmatrix{-\frac12t^2+\frac13t^3\\\frac12t^2+\frac16t^3+\frac13t^4}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, LutzL! I understand most of your answer, but where does the $\frac{1}{t^2}$ come from?

Comment: $Φ(t)^2=t^2I$, thus $Φ(t)^{-1}=t^{-2}Φ(t)$.